# Adding a subview through CATransiton animation. How to reverse animation / dismiss it properly?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have the following view which comes in from the bottom.

```
- (void)add:(id)sender {


MyAddViewController *controller = [[MyAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAddViewController" bundle:nil];
//controller.delegate = self;

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.35;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
//NSLog(@"%s: self.view.window=%@", __func__, self.view.window);
UIView *containerView = controller.view;
[containerView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
   }
```

It works good. My issue with getting rid of it. How do I reverse the animation so that it slides down off the screen? I've created a button for it but can't seem to get the transition correct? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the UIView animations, may be enough:

```
- (void)closeYourController{
   CGPoint initialCenter = controller.view.center;
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     controller.view.center = CGPointMake(initialCenter.x, initialCenter.y + 480); // to go down
     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(aMethodToBeCalledAfterAnimationEnd:finished:context:)];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)aMethodToBeCalledAfterAnimationEnd:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context{
    [controller.view removeFromSuperView];
    //  [controller release]; //// ...if needed

}
```